# Javascript configurable attribute

Tags: javascript

If the property of the object in Javascript was set to configurable == false can we configure it back? Or is there any ways we can delete this or set it back to true?

By configurable attribute, I mean using Object.defineProperty() method.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking? But you can generally set any attribute to whatever you want in javascript? `var bla = { configurable:false }; bla.configurable = true;`

Comment: i'm not really sure why people down vote my question. I think they should comment first before doing anything. :)

Comment: For setting property you need to use = , not == . Once a true configurable property is changed to false, none of the properties can be changed , including configurable itself. We get TypeError if we try to do so.

Answer (score 3):

> If the property of the object in Javascript was set to configurable == false can we configure it back?

No, hence the name.